# How to run shell script in jenkins pipeline

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run shell script from jenkins pipeline, instead of calling shell script can I run `sh` commands one by one like below

```
top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "%.2f%%\t\t\n", $(NF-2)}'
free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "%.2f%%\t\t", $3*100/$2 }'
iostat -c 3 3 |awk '/^ /{print $4}'|awk  '{ printf( "%s ", $1 ); } END { printf( "\n" ); }'
```

I am new to jenkins but when I try to use it with `sh` like below its giving error

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Check System Usage') {
            steps {
                script {
                     def CPUUSAGE = sh (script: "top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "%.2f%%\t\t\n", $(NF-2)}'", returnStdout: true).trim() as Integer
                     def MEMUSAGE = sh (script:free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "%.2f%%\t\t", $3*100/$2 }'", returnStdout: true).trim() as Integer
                     def IOWAIT = sh (script:"iostat -c 3 3 |awk '/^ /{print $4}'|awk  '{ printf( "%s ", $1 ); } END { printf( "\n" ); }'", returnStdout: true).trim() as Integer
                     println("CPUUSAGE = ${CPUUSAGE}","MEMUSAGE = ${MEMUSAGE}","IOWAIT = {IOWAIT}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you guide what is the exact format to run shell command in jenkins file, or can you share sample code for reference.

Comment: Don't you have an extra quote `"` after the `awk` command?

Comment: In `CPUUSAGE`, you don't escape quote, I think you should (internal `"` --> `\"`)

Comment: @Mathieu  can you guide what exactly I am doing wrong because its working fine in Linux terminal , I am new to jenkins not sure how linux terminal is working 
                     
getting illegal string body error

Comment: you need to escape all " quotes with \" inside "", ' can be used normally, your second sh script is not quoted. only "" quoted strings will be expanded inside jenkins.

Answer (score -1):

You are using "" and '' incorrect.